# How to match multiple lines starting with a TAB, and the line before the 1st one in a group?

Tags: command-line, awk, grep

I've got some third party log files I'm trying to pull errors out of on the command line.

The logs look like this:

```
time=1
time=2
time=3
  at com.test.com....
  at com.test.com....
  at com.test2.com....
time=4
time=5
time=6
time=7
time=8
time=9
  at org.badstuff.com...
  at org.badstuff.com...
  at org.badstuff.com...
time=10
time=11
```

The lines that start with `at` start with a TAB character, so they can be easily matched.

How can I pull these stack traces out of this file, *and* a couple of lines before the first stack trace each time? I'm on a Mac, but would prefer a generic solution that works on Mac/Linux if possible, as I have to work on both quite often.

So from my above example, I'd pull out the following

```
time=2
time=3
  at com.test.com....
  at com.test.com....
  at com.test2.com....
time=8
time=9
  at org.badstuff.com...
  at org.badstuff.com...
  at org.badstuff.com...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `-A`fter context, `-B`efore context or `-C`ontext option in `grep`, e.g. to fit to your example:

```
grep -B2 '^\t' file
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `grep -B2 -P '^\t' logfile` to pick up two lines before each set of matches. You may need to mask out the group separator "--" that is inserted between matches.

Results

```
$ grep -B2 -P '^\t' /tmp/t
time=2
time=3
        at com.test.com....
        at com.test.com....
        at com.test2.com....
--
time=8
time=9
        at org.badstuff.com...
        at org.badstuff.com...
        at org.badstuff.com...
```